# error:Must declare the scalar variable "@ID" asp.net & sql server2014

Tags: asp.net, oledb, sql-server-2014

**asp.net & sql server 2014 : why this error appearMust declare the scalar variable"@ID"  I looked on goggle and I think it has something to do with insert parameters for ID. Then again I read there could be a typo error.
As I am not going to insert ID column manually I think this is why I am having problem(s) and I don't know how to solve this problem. i cant find out what is missing or wrong could you help please**

```
        string query = "insert into LegRent(ID, Day, Date, Name, Nationality, relegon, NatID, Name2, Nationality2, relegon2, NatID2, Type, Building, Flat, UseFor, Duration, StartFrom, EndIn, RentValue, OnlyAr, YearPercent, InsuranceValue, OnlyArInsur, Addres2, Addres) values (@ID, @Day, @Date, @Name, @Nationality, @relegon, @NatID, @Name2, @Nationality2, @relegon2, @NatID2,  @Type, @Building, @Flat, @UseFor, @Duration, @StartFrom, @EndIn, @RentValue, @OnlyAr, @YearPercent, @InsuranceValue, @OnlyArInsur,  @Addres2, @Addres)";

        try
        {

            string query2 = "Select @@Identity";
            int ID;
            string connect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Construction;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            using (OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(connect))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn2))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idtxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", daytxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", datetxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", namedd.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", ddNati.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relegon", ddRelgon.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NatID", NatIDtxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name2", namedd2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality2", ddNati2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relegon2", ddRelgon2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NatID2", NatIDtxt2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", typrdd.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building", buileddd.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flat", flatdd.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UseFor", usetxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Duration", durationtxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartFrom", starttxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndIn", endtxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RentValue", vluetxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnlyAr", onlytxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InsuranceValue", insurtxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnlyArInsur", insuronlytxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearPercent", percenttxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres2", adresstxt2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres", adresstxt.Text);

                    conn2.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.CommandText = query2;
                    ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    lbl_msg.Text = "تـــم الحفظ";

                    int rentMonths = 0;

                    bool isInt = int.TryParse(durationtxt.Text, out rentMonths);

                    if (isInt)
                    {
                        for (int index = 0; index < rentMonths; index++)
                        {
                            OleDbCommand insertRentMonths = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[AccRentReceipt] ([ReceiptID] ,[ContractID] ,[Name]) VALUES (@ReceiptID ,@ContractID ,@Name)", conn2);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReceiptID", index + 1);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractID", ID);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", namedd.Text);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_msg.Text = "خطــــأ " + ex.Message;

        }
```

Comment: `idtxt.Text` is probably empty. Set a break point and check.

Comment: @VDWWD it's not empty

Comment: check your database if you make id identity then you should insert data without id

Comment: post your table schema

Comment: it's not identity

Comment: what is the data type ?? and value you are storing ??

Comment: data type is int